# Distributive as a lattice if and only if distributive as a semilattice?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $(X,\leq)$ be a lattice.

$(X,\leq)$ is said to be distributive when for any $x$, $y$ and $z$ in $X$ it holds that
\begin{equation*}
x\wedge(y\vee z) = (x\wedge y)\vee(x\wedge z),
\end{equation*}
or equivalently
\begin{equation*}
x\vee(y\wedge z) = (x\vee y)\wedge(x\vee z).
\end{equation*}

$(X,\leq)$ is said to be distributive as a meet-semilattice
when for any $x$, $y$ and $z$ in $X$,
if $y\wedge z\leq x$ then there are $y'$ and $z'$ in $X$
such that $y\leq y'$ and $z\leq z'$ and $y'\wedge z' = x$.

If $(X,\leq)$ is distributive as a lattice,
then for any $x$, $y$ and $z$ in $X$
satisfying $y\wedge z\leq x$ it holds that
\begin{equation*}
x = x\vee(y\wedge z) = (x\vee y)\wedge(x\vee z)
\end{equation*}
and $y\leq x\vee y$ and $z\leq x\vee z$,
so $(X,\leq)$ is distributive as a meet-semilattice.

According to
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributivity_(order_theory)#Distributivity_for_semilattices)
the converse implication also holds true:
if $(X,\leq)$ is distributive as a meet-semilattice
then it is a distributive lattice.

**My question:** How to show that
if $(X,\leq)$ is distributive as a meet-semilattice
then it is a distributive lattice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not a distributive lattice, then it has a sub-lattice isomorphic either to the diamond $M_3$ or the pentagon $N_5$.

It's easy to check that neither of these is distributive as a semi-lattice.
In the case of $M_3$, just take $x,y,z$ to be the atoms;
in the case of $N_5$, take, for example
$$0\prec x \prec z \prec 1 \quad\text{and}\quad 0 \prec y \prec 1.$$

---

While all of the above is true, it doesn't prove that a distributive semilattice which is also a lattice is a distributive lattice.
The reason is that the condition that defines distributive semilattices is not equational (or quasi-equational for that matter) and so, for the best of my knowledge, distributive semilattices don't form a class closed for the formation of subalgebras.

It turns out, it's not difficult to produce a direct proof.
So suppose that a lattice $L$ satisfies the condition
$$x\leq y \vee z \implies \exists y',z' \left( y'\leq y,\, z'\leq z,\, x=y'\vee z' \right).$$
Now we want to prove that $L$ satisfies
$$x\land (y\lor z)=(x\land y)\lor(x\land z).$$
Certainly $L$ (as all lattices) satisfy
$$x\land (y\lor z)\geq(x\land y)\lor(x\land z),$$
so we have to prove the converse.
But
$$x\land (y \lor z) \leq y \lor z,$$
and so there exist $y'\leq y$ and $z'\leq z$ such that
$$x\land(y\lor z)=y'\lor z'.$$
But then it follows that $x\geq y'\vee z'$, and so $x\geq y'$ and $x\geq z'$, yielding
$$y'=x\wedge y' \quad\text{and}\quad z'=x\wedge z'.$$
Hence
$$x\land(y\lor z)=(x\land y')\lor(x\land z')\leq (x\land y)\lor (x\land z).$$

Comment: Thanks! Reading about the $M_3$-$M_5$ theorem now for the first time (due to your first remark), wouldn't have thought of looking in that direction myself!

Comment: @Bart Maybe I should have mentioned the characterization of distributive lattices in terms of $M_3-N_5$ lattices as sub-lattices. It is, indeed, very useful, in a lot of situations.